# Rails Devise - Routes Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was installing the Devise gem, and everything seemed to be going according to tutorial. I got to the point where I was able to register a user, but then at some point I'm not sure what happened and I started getting routes errors:

```
No route matches [GET] "/projects"
```

Except, my routes file has been unchanged and has quite a few routes in it.

Any suggestions?

As requested the result of rake routes:
http://pastebin.com/FB17DhYq

Comment: could you share the results of `rake routes`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FB17DhYq

Comment: The route is present there. Restart the server.

Comment: I can't do that... It's a shared environment and I don't have the privileges to

Comment: can you post your routes.rb file?

Comment: Here is part of it (it is rather long) please let me know if you need more: http://pastebin.com/meSF2ebn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't restart/reload the server than try to reload the routes adding to the controller (some that works and you can hit it):

`Rails.application.reload_routes!` for Rails4 or `ActionController::Routing::Routes.reload!` for previous versions.

You can add just the line above or use this:

```
before_filter :reload_routes

  private
    def reload_routes
      Rails.application.reload_routes! # for Rails 4
      # ActionController::Routing::Routes.reload! # for previous

    end
```

Comment: Done, added it at the start of projects_controller.rb as that is the route, now getting... undefined method `devise' for #<Class:0x007fec987a9b30> and  This error occurred while loading the following files:
   /srv/homes/aca12dp/projects/project3/config/routes.rb

Comment: I believe it's just one server

Comment: Hi, no, I only have a before_action defined

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Let's remove this chat as it doesn't contain anything useful for others.